# PDF OCR Google cloud vision keep spacing

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I don't know if it's possible, but I'm receiving forms in PDF format.  I need to take the text from the PDF in the exact same position it is in the file and place it in a text document I can parse like:

Line 4  startCharacter 50 endcharacter 60

This would give me whatever text is in that position.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible to do this. I found a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/120628290) made to Cloud Vision API to take a PDF file and export it as a searchable PDF which might resolve this issue. I recommend you to subscribe to the Feature Request (click on the star next to the title) so it can get more visibility.

In the meantime, you can check the [documentation on PDFs recognition](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) to try it out and see if you can get the desired behavior.

If the forms you are working with have a determined format, you might be able to solve the issue by going through the [TextAnnotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#TextAnnotation) response from the API. The response gives you the text, plus additional insights on it, like the pages, paragraphs, etc.